# Facebook Authentication in Background - C# sdk

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I am developing a windows phone app using facebook c# sdk. I created a login page to authenticate the user and it also working well. But my problem is, next time when the user open the app, it should be navigated to main page and do the authentication work in background. Is there anyway to do this??

I used `navigatedto` override method to "redirect the user into the mainpage". I dont know how to authenticate the user in background. Help plss..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save token (received from fb) in ur isolated storage & check if it invalid in ur HomePage and so accordingly navigate to Login (if invalid)